Error in sqllite3 when running apt update
I'm on Ubuntu 24.04.
When I run sudo apt update I get the following error ouput:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 9, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_enable_load_extension
Reading package lists... Done

E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code



when running:
ldd /usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
my output is this:
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc32f1e000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007db35d69a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007db35d400000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007db35d67e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007db35d317000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007db35d679000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007db35d802000)


as you see in the this line:
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
its a completely other library than what apt update is trying to load.
and when I run dpkg -L libsqlite3-0 my output is:
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libsqlite3-0
/usr/share/doc/libsqlite3-0/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libsqlite3-0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libsqlite3-0/copyright
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0


I'm not very good at linux and don't know how to fix this. Any detailed help would be appreciated.

I faced a similar issue, where the same library you mention was overriden by Filezilla (it pointed to /opt/filezilla/lib).
For the time being I've mitigated the issue by replacing the library pointed to with a symbolic link pointing to the standard sqlite3 library.
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 /opt/filezilla/lib/libsqlite3.so.0

